# TypeError: elem is null on upgrading to jquery 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone code like following

```
owned: function(){
    this.url = this.options.url.owned;
    this.parse = function(users){
        return users.map(function(user){
            return user;
        });
    };
    this.fetch({
        data: {
            screen_name : login
        }
    });
}
```

when i execute the code i get the following jquery error

```
TypeError: elem is null
return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();
```

this is happening after upgrading the jquery library to 1.10. Before i had 1.8.3 and everything was working fine.

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users/suggestions",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Collection<User> suggestions() {
    String login = authenticationService.getCurrentUserLightVersion().getLogin();
    return suggestionService.suggestUsers(login);
}
```

The response is properly coming but i thing there is some problem with the *parse* method now. Is it possible it's giving such error because the collection is empty. But in 1.8.3 jquery was correctly executing the parse on empty collection.
Any clues.?

Comment: What's the point of the map function?

Comment: i.e have you tried replacing `return users.map(...)` with `return users.slice()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 1.9+ is more strict in parsing ajax responses than <= 1.8.x.
For example if you GET document with Content-Type: application/json but with empty response, it will execute jxhr.error, because empty string is not valid JSON data.
 So before you start debug your code, try to debug requests.